# Curve merged but weird twist happens?

Tags: bezier-curves

So I'm making a track for my car to ride over and I've been working with curve tilt. This weird twist shows up at the point where I merge the ends of the curve together. I already tried to remove the segment and remerge (if that's a word) it. Doesn't work.
Any ideas?[image]

I already made it cyclic and I started tilting it but of some reason It does this even when redoing the merge. There is a full twist somewhere else on the track so that is probably a reason.

Comment: Why don't you make the curve cyclic before shaping it ? In edit mode 'alt + C'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that in the **Global Transforms** the segments have the same tilt:

When two segments have different tilt (90 and -90) you'll get a loop when you connect:

[image]

Wehn the segments have the same tilt, the segment will be straight:

[image]

If one of your segments is flipped try this:

Deselect all (<kbd>A</kbd>)

Select one control point and then select linked (<kbd>L</kbd>)

Rotate the whole segment 180 degrees by adding +180 on the *Mean Tilt* section.

Link it then with the other section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a half twist to me. Somewhere else on the track you must have a half twist, which results in the normals of the joining segments going in opposite Z directions.

Comment: No it's really a whole twist. There is only a cocscrew in the track. That is a full twist. At the right you see the top of the track and on the left as well. It's defenitely a full twist.

Comment: I see it now. The right side of the screen cap was confusing to me. Carry on!

Answer (score 0):

**Vertical Segments Confuse Blender**
Avoid making a Curve cyclic while one of your end segments are perfectly vertical (Z-Axis). I guess Blender gets confused in this case.
My solution was simply to "Make Cyclic" at another spot in the curve.